# Multiple has_one in model polymorphic relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Company model that looks like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :visiting_address, -> { where "addressable_type = 'visiting_address'" }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
  has_one :billing_address, -> { where "addressable_type = 'billing_address'" }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
  has_one :delivery_address, -> { where "addressable_type = 'delivery_address'" }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy

  def visiting_address=(address)
     super
     address.update_attribute(:addressable_type, "visiting_address")
  end

  def delivery_address=(address)
     super
     address.update_attribute(:addressable_type, "delivery_address")
  end

  def billing_address=(address)
     super
     address.update_attribute(:addressable_type, "billing_address")
 end
end
```

And i have my Address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And everything seems to work correctly but that is not true. I fired 'rails c' and tried to create some models and associate them. And it works, so i go and save transactions in the database and exit console. I fire it again and fetch the company and try to access billing address, but i get nil, always.

I can see this query that is executing and it's wrong:

```
SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses"  WHERE "addresses"."addressable_id" = ? AND     "addresses"."addressable_type" = ? AND (addressable_type = 'billing_address') LIMIT 1  [["addressable_id", 1], ["addressable_type", "Company"]]
```

Why is doing that query but before i saved and exited when i called c.billing_address i was getting the right address, and now it's nil.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That actually worked in console?  I don't think `super` does what you think it does.  Do you have the ability to change the structure?  Because single table inheritance would make more sense to me here than polymorphic associations.

Comment: Well here it is http://i.imgur.com/r4m5iNz.png , works there. But i used polymorphic because i have more models that have address as an attribute.
As far as super, doesn't that just call what it would call normally if i haven't override it?

Comment: `super` calls a method in the parent object with the same name, passing all arguments.  The parent object here is `ActiveRecord::Base` .  Honestly I would switch to STI.  So you have an `Address` class and inherit from that `BillingAddress`, `DeliveryAddress` classes e.t.c.